# Filter directory when using shutil.copytree?

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

Is there a way I can filter a directory by using the absolute path to it?

```
shutil.copytree(directory,
                target_dir,
                ignore = shutil.ignore_patterns("/Full/Path/To/aDir/Common"))
```

This doesn't seem to work when trying to filter the "Common" Directory located under "`aDir`". If I do this:

```
shutil.copytree(directory,
                target_dir,
                ignore = shutil.ignore_patterns("Common"))
```

It works, but every directory called Common will be filtered in that "tree", which is not what I want.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make your own ignore function:

```
shutil.copytree('/Full/Path', 'target',
              ignore=lambda directory, contents: ['Common'] if directory == '/Full/Path/To/aDir' else [])
```

Or, if you want to be able to call `copytree` with a relative path:

```
import os.path
def ignorePath(path):
  def ignoref(directory, contents):
    return (
        f for f in contents
        if os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory, f)) == path)
  return ignoref

shutil.copytree('Path', 'target', ignore=ignorePath('/Full/Path/To/aDir/Common'))
```

From the docs:

> If ignore is given, it must be a callable that will receive as its
> arguments the directory being visited by copytree(), and a list of its
> contents, as returned by os.listdir(). Since copytree() is called
> recursively, the ignore callable will be called once for each
> directory that is copied. The callable must return a sequence of
> directory and file names relative to the current directory (i.e. a
> subset of the items in its second argument); these names will then be
> ignored in the copy process. ignore_patterns() can be used to create
> such a callable that ignores names based on glob-style patterns.

Comment: Small correction, ignoref function should return list (i.e. [f for f in ...] instead of generator.

Comment: Another correction; os.abspath should be os.path.abspath

Comment: @MarkE.Hamilton Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The API for shutil.ignore_patterns() doesn't support absolute paths, but it is trivially easy to roll your own variant.

As a starting point, look at the source code for *ignore_patterns*:

```
def ignore_patterns(*patterns):
    """Function that can be used as copytree() ignore parameter.

    Patterns is a sequence of glob-style patterns
    that are used to exclude files"""
    def _ignore_patterns(path, names):
        ignored_names = []
        for pattern in patterns:
            ignored_names.extend(fnmatch.filter(names, pattern))
        return set(ignored_names)
    return _ignore_patterns
```

You can see that it returns a function that accepts a path and list of names, and it returns a set of names to ignore.  To support your use case, create you own similar function that uses takes advantage of *path* argument.  Pass your function to the ignore parameter in the call to *copytree()*.

Alternatively, don't use *shutil* as-is.  The source code is short and sweet, so it isn't hard to cut, paste, and customize.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to make your own ignore function, which checks the current directory being processed and returns a list containing 'Common' only if the dir is '/Full/Path/To/aDir'.

```
def ignore_full_path_common(dir, files):
    if dir == '/Full/Path/To/aDir':
        return ['Common']
    return []

shutil.copytree(directory, target_dir, ignore=ignore_full_path_common)
```

Answer (score 2):

Many Thanks for the answer. It helped me to design my own `ignore_patterns()` function for a bit different requirement. Pasting the code here, it might help someone.

Below is the `ignore_patterns()` function for excluding multiple files/directories using the absolute path to it.

`myExclusionList` --> List containing files/directories to be excluded while copying. This list can contain wildcard pattern. Paths in the list are relative to the `srcpath` provided. For ex:

**[EXCLUSION LIST]**

```
java/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/test
unittests
python-buildreqs/apps/abc.tar.gz
3rd-party/jdk*
```

**Code is pasted below**

```
def copydir(srcpath, dstpath, myExclusionList, log):

    patternlist = []
    try:
        # Forming the absolute path of files/directories to be excluded
        for pattern in myExclusionList:
            tmpsrcpath = join(srcpath, pattern)
            patternlist.extend(glob.glob(tmpsrcpath)) # myExclusionList can contain wildcard pattern hence glob is used
        copytree(srcpath, dstpath, ignore=ignore_patterns_override(*patternlist))
    except (IOError, os.error) as why:
        log.warning("Unable to copy %s to %s because %s", srcpath, dstpath, str(why))
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
    except Error as err:
        log.warning("Unable to copy %s to %s because %s", srcpath, dstpath, str(err))


# [START: Ignore Patterns]
# Modified Function to ignore patterns while copying.
# Default Python Implementation does not exclude absolute path
# given for files/directories

def ignore_patterns_override(*patterns):
    """Function that can be used as copytree() ignore parameter.
    Patterns is a sequence of glob-style patterns
    that are used to exclude files/directories"""
    def _ignore_patterns(path, names):
        ignored_names = []
        for f in names:
            for pattern in patterns:
                if os.path.abspath(join(path, f)) == pattern:
                    ignored_names.append(f)
        return set(ignored_names)
    return _ignore_patterns

# [END: Ignore Patterns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Platform independent. Paths glob patterns  [".gitkeep","app/build","*.txt"]

```py
    def callbackIgnore(paths):
        """ callback for shutil.copytree """
        def ignoref(directory, contents):
            arr = [] 
            for f in contents:
                for p in paths:
                    if (pathlib.PurePath(directory, f).match(p)):
                        arr.append(f)
            return arr
    
        return ignoref
```