# Move certain files from specific subdirectories into a new directory

Tags: python, shell, csv

How do I move only certain files (not all files), from specific subdirectories (not all subdirectories), into a new directory?

The files that need to be moved have been listed in a CSV file and are about 85,000 in number. They have been mentioned  with their absolute paths. All the files possess the same extension, i.e., `.java`. The number of specific subdirectories is about 13,000.

Is there a Python script (preferred) or a Shell script to do this?

N.B: The forums that I searched on returned solutions on how to move *all* files from within a *single* subdirectory into a new directory. They are mentioned below:

1. https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/473187/copymove-all-sub-directories-from-a-folder-to-another-folder-using-python
2. http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-copy-a-file-in-python-with-shutil/
3. [Filter directory when using shutil.copytree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842044/filter-directory-when-using-shutil-copytree)
4. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207375/copy-certain-files-from-specified-subdirectories-into-a-separate-subdirectory

Comment: 1) Create a list of these certain directories 2) Loop over them 3) Move these certain files (or just *.java) to your destination.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what this CSV file looks like? Does it contain the absolute path of the file/directories you are moving and the absolute path to where they need to be moved?

Comment: The CSV file contains only 1 column (without a title).The 1st row: /home/shaw/Documents//Dataset/ANT/Repository/ChangedMethodFiles/bab9e2d799ee887bc0a404b4acdec0366234eafe/930587b01d54c1800f7cde3695b86d06.java                                                     The remaining rows are similar to this one, with only the  last 2 entities changing (ie the actual java file, and the folder containing it).It contains the absolute path of the file/directories I'm moving but not the absolute path to where they need to be moved.

Comment: Ignore the double-slashes after 'Documents', it's actually a single slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your CSV file looks like this:

```
George,/home/geo/mtvernon.java,Betsy
Abe,/home/honest/gettys.java,Mary
```

You could move the files using this shell command:

```bash
$ cut -d, -f2 < x.csv | xargs -I '{}'  mv '{}' /home/me/new-directory
```

Comment: The 1st 3 lines  of my csv file (/home/shaw/Desktop/SHAW_AntUnderstand.csv) look like this:                                                                                                                /home/shaw/Documents/Dataset/ANT/Repository/ChangedMethodFiles/bab9e2d799ee887bc0a404b4acdec036/7b01d54c1800f7cde36956d06.java

Comment: /home/shaw/Documents/Dataset/ANT/Repository/ChangedMethodFiles/20ab59bff57796a67e1cdfefbc29826e/f132a91640114b9d51804dd7.java

Comment: /home/shaw/Documents/Dataset/ANT/Repository/ChangedMethodFiles/8ce1de2178a0422105fa437c327bf3/b2933bb3d32ef7d12d5f40a.java

Comment: I ran the following:  shaw@shaw-XPS-8700:~/Desktop$                         cut -d, -f1 <  /home/shaw/Desktop/SHAW_AntUnderstand.csv | xargs -I  '{}'  mv  '{}'  /home/shaw/Desktop/ANT_85K

Comment: (My csv file has only 1 column, hence I used -f1)

Comment: I got a series of errors,all of the type:                                                     mv: cannot stat ‘/home/shaw/Documents/Dataset/ANT/Repository/ChangedMethodFiles/07382b400af7ecebc64eff5c55b4f56/de0fa0428b3da0c13c6b2a3.java’: No such file or directory

Comment: However, when I physically check the paths; these sub-folders and files are definitely present. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't know what is causing that.

Comment: Thanks Rob...your answer is neat and  concise. It worked well. The reason why it didn't work the previous time  was that I had specified the wrong address for some files.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
import os
import csv

def move_file(old_file_path, new_directory):
    if not os.path.isdir(new_directory):
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    base_name = os.path.basename(old_file_path)
    new_file_path = os.path.join(new_directory, base_name)
    os.rename(old_file_path, new_file_path)

def parse_csv_file(csv_path):
    csv_file = open(csv_path)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    paths = list(csv_reader)
    csv_file.close()
    return paths

if __name__ == '__main__':
    old_file_paths = parse_csv_file('your_csv_path')
    for old_file_path in old_file_paths:
        move_file(old_file_path, 'your_new_directory')
```

This assumes that your CSV file only contains paths, delimited by commas, and all of those files exist.

Comment: When I tried running this, the comparison between 'files mentioned in the CSV file' and 'all files mentioned in the old path' did not occur. i.e( The entire old folder was moved into the new directory; not just specific files from the old folder). Am I missing something?

Comment: Try just running the first line and seeing whether `len(old_file_paths)` produces a reasonable value.